# git config insteadOf for https://host/project/<project>/repo/<repo>

Tags: git, ssh, config, git-clone, git-config

`git config <url>.insteadOf <url>` is  working flawlessly and easy for simple URL schemes like GitHub or GitLab.

In corporate network I have HTTPS URL, which looks like `https://host/project/<project>/repo/<repo>` and SSH URL looks like `git@host/<project>/<repo>.git` (where `.git` at the end is optional.

Is it possible to use the mechanism `git`provides to convert from one to another or I have to write a one-liner to wrap git-clone?

Answer (score 3):

From [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf):

> url.<base>.insteadOf
> Any URL that **starts** with this value will be rewritten to **start**, instead, with <base>.

(emphasize mine - *phd*)

So `insteadOf` cannot parse URLs, extract substrings and put them in different order. Only the start of the URL can be rewritten.

Comment: ok, I'll try to find some workarounds

Answer (score 2):

I use it for my corporate on-premise Git hosting service, provided, as phd suggest, I use the beginning of the URL.

The fact that the end of the URL might or might not include .git does not matter, as our Git repository hosting server will interpret both the same way.

From SSH to HTTPS:

```
git config --global url."https://host/".insteadOf git@host:
git config --global url."https://host/".insteadOf ssh://git@host/
```

From HTTPS to SSH:

```
git config --global url."ssh://git@host/".insteadOf https://host/
```

Comment: @EirNym Note the SSH URL syntax: `git@host/<project>/<repo>.git` would not work. It would need to be either `git@host;<project>/<repo>.git` (with `:` instead of '`/`'), or `ssh;//git@host/<project>/<repo>.git` (with `ssh://` prefix)

Comment: ok, I'll try to use sed for that.